# XmlReaderSettings CheckCharacters=false doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a xml response from a Rest service. I'm implementing IXmlSerializable because the xml is rather specific and I do custom serializing. The response contains illegal xml characters but as I have no way to modify the xml I'll have to deal with them.

The solution seems simple : when creating my XmlReader I feed it XmlSetting with ChecCharacters set to false :

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.CheckCharacters = false;

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings))
{
    var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(RootElement);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), xRoot);
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

When checking the CheckCharacters is effectively set to false.

But I still keep getting errors like :

```
{"'', hexadecimal value 0x01, is an invalid character. Line 9, position 55."}
```

I thought the CheckCharacters=false setting was intended to avoid throwing errors because of illegal Xml characters ?

Any idea where I make a mistake, why the errors keep on being thrown ?

thnx in advance..
Raf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.checkcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the XmlReader is processing text data, it always checks that the XML names and text content are valid, regardless of the property setting. Setting CheckCharacters to false turns off character checking for character entity references.

So setting `CheckCharacters` to `false` won't allow to you parse invalid XML.

You can try to replace binary characters with escapes: `'\x01'` with `"&#01;"` etc. `XmlReader` with disabled `CheckCharacters` seems to accept those.

Comment: Thnx Soner for such a quick response.  Your answer explains why I keep getting errors...  But not sure how to replace all binary chars with escapes...  I'll look for a regex..  anyway I'll accept your answer because it stopped me wasting my time on the CheckCharacters setting :)

Comment: You can use XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(s) to remove invalid chars from a string before reading as xml. This is a better alternative to using regex.

Comment: Is there any way we can get by using this flag for xml string? How is this flag supposed to be used? I also tried creating a memory stream from xml string. My xml string contains xml elements with names starting with numeric characters.

Comment: @AnujGeek In contrast with HTML, XML is designed to be strict. Either XML is valid, or can't be parsed at all, there's no middle ground, there's no quirks mode, no backtracking from error state. Standard-compliant XML parsers are *disallowed* to parse invalid XML. So if your XML is invalid, fix your XML. This is the only way. If you want to parse invalid XML, it's no longer XML, so you have to write your own parser to work with your format. `CheckCharacters` should never be used, it's a hack.

Comment: @Athari Even if I can get a hack to work for now, it'll be a huge relief. The xml which is having names starting with numbers is coming from Adobe Acrobat AcroForms. Creating my own parser will be a huge task, please let me know if I can get this hack work in any way. Please see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532818/making-xmlreadersettings-checkcharacters-work-for-xml-string